# Clear list when number of elements exceeds N

Tags: list

I have a list, and want to clear it with `(setq slist '())`.  But I only want to do this when the number of elements exceeds the value `N`.

Comment: `(when (> N (length slist)) (setq slist nil))`.  Check out the on-board introduction to emacs lisp: `C-h R eintr` which will help you answer several of your recent questions.

Comment: Have seen `(setq slist '())`.  Is `(setq slist nil)` preferable for reading?

Comment: Since `(eq nil '())` is true, it doesn't matter which you use.  I think the latter is less noisy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using this macro

```
(defmacro normalize-list(l n)
  "empties the list L when its size reaches N"
  `(if(>=(length ,l),n)(setq ,l '())))
```

Examples

```
(setq slist'(foo bar baz)) ;->(foo bar baz)

(normalize-list slist 2);->nil

slist ;->(foo bar baz)

(normalize-list slist 5);->nil

slist;->nil
```

Comment: Why do you need a macro for this?

Comment: The argument l (for the list) must not be evaluated. In case l is bound to '(foo bar baz) What would elisp (setq l'()) render if the symbol l is evaluated?  And what about (length l) if the argument l is quoted ?

Comment: yup, good point.  I was not thinking clearly earlier.